# Remove/Add LI to UL single redraw

Tags: jquery

I'm new to JQuery/Javascript. Have a JSON object that contains an array of strings I want to add to an unordered list. First I need to remove all existing `li` children from the `ul`, then I want to add each element of my string array as a `li` - but I think it will be important to add them all at the same time to avoid flicker from redraw?

Anyway, I don't know how to do it. I'm seeing examples of bits and pieces and have created the following code, but it has problems. It seems to remove all `li` children and it will add a `li`, but it keeps overwriting the last `li` added.

```
var features = product.Attributes.Features
$('ul.feature').children('li').each(function () { $(this).remove(); });
if (features) {
    var li = $('<li></li>');
    for (var feature in features) {
        $('ul.feature').append(li);
        $(li).text(features[feature]);
    }
}
```

`var features` is an array. I tried using `if (features.Length > 0) {` but `Length` always shows `undefined` when I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove All li:

```
$('ul.feature').find('li').remove();
```

Add an li:

```
var liText = "Li Text";
$('ul.feature').append('<li>'+liText+'</li>');
```